# How to get current html value of a class with click on another class element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I fetching data from database, In which i want to get current class html value with on click on another nearest class, And show it on another input tag.

**script**

```
while($row = $query->fetch(PDO:: FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $player= $row->['player'];
    $runs = $row->['runs'];
    $balss= $row->['balls'];

    $Name = "<strong class='player'> $player </strong>"; 
    $score = "<i class='runs'> $runs </i>";
    $balls= "<i class='balls'> $balls</i>";

    }

<div class="popup">
<input type="text" id="player" >
<input type="text" id="runs" >
<input type="text" id="balls" >
</div>


$(document).on('click', '.player', function(){
    $(".popup").toggle();
    var player = document.getElementsByClassName('player');
    for (var i = 0; i < player.length; i++)
    $("#player").val(player[i].html);

    var score = document.getElementsByClassName('runs');
    for (var i = 0; i < score.length; i++)
    $("#runs").val(score[i].html);
});
```

Comment: please show the rendered output of your server-side language or give an example of the output. Thank you

Comment: @NewToJS output should be like (**smith**  39 , **Taylor**  57 , **Dany**  28 )

Comment: What about my answer? I'm I missed anything? @Dishko

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use `$(this)` and `.next()` from Jquery to make it work.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.player', function(){
    var player = $(this).data('name');
    var runs = $(this).data('runs');
    $(".popup").show();
    $("#player").val(player);
    $("#runs").val(runs);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<strong class='player' data-name='player1' data-runs='20'> player1 </strong>
<i class='runs'> 20 </i>
<br>
<strong class='player' data-name='player2' data-runs='30'> player2 </strong>
<i class='runs'> 30 </i>
<br>
<strong class='player' data-name='player3' data-runs='59'> player3 </strong>
<i class='runs'> 59 </i>
<br>
<strong class='player' data-name='player4' data-runs='46'> player4 </strong>
<i class='runs'> 46 </i>

<br>
<br>

<div class="popup" style="display:none">
<input type="text" id="player" >
<input type="text" id="runs" >
</div>
```

**Edited**

I think you can handle this situation better with the `data` attribute. By simply changing your PHP part like below.

```
while($row = $query->fetch(PDO:: FETCH_ASSOC)) {
 $player= $row->['player'];
 $runs = $row->['runs'];
 $Name = "<strong class='player' data-name='$player' data-runs='$runs'> $player </strong>"; 
 $score = "<i class='runs'> $runs </i>";
}
```

Comment: sorry if I use  more more than 1 classes near, than what should i use instead of `next()`    .